# Get build configuration details using Jenkins API

Tags: ruby, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am looking for a way to get the configuration details of a Jenkins job using Jenkins API. Something which is displayed in the command block in the below image.

[image]

Has anybody tried getting configuration details using Jenkins API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the raw XML configuration of a job from the URL: `http://jenkins:8080/job/my-job/config.xml`

This URL returns the persistent job configuration in XML. The build steps are listed under the `builders` element, different types of build steps are identified by different elements:

```
<builders>
  <hudson.tasks.Shell>
    <command>
    # Run my shell command...
    </command>
  </hudson.tasks.Shell>
</builders>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way of doing this that I know of, however you can collect the shell execution with the console output API and a little regex magic.

The API endpoint looks like this:

```
"http://#{server}:#{port}/job/#{job_name}/{build_numer}/logText/progressiveText?start=0"
```

For this example, let's say your shell command looks like:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rspec spec/
```

The console puts a `+` before every execution command, so the following script would work:

```
# using rest-client gem for ease of use 
# but you could use net:http and open/uri in the standard library
require 'rest-client'

console_output = RestClient.get 'http://jenkins_server:80/job/my_job/100/logtext/progressiveText?start=0'

console_output.scan(/^\+.+/).each_with_object([]) { |match, array| array << match.gsub('+ ', '') }
#=> ["bundle install", "bundle exec rspec spec/"]
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks! I will give it a try. BTW by execution_number you mean build number right?

Comment: Thanks Johnson! The solution you provided works. In my case, the answer left by Dave seems to work best.

Comment: Yeah, Dave's answer is definitely the solution. TIL!